# php script which updates svn working directory

Tags: php, svn

I want to write a php script which updates svn working directory

I tried with below code , but it does not work.I guess because the USER for php script is "apache" but for svn update it needs to be "homeuser"

```
    putenv("USERNAME=homeuser");
    putenv("HOME=/home/homeuser");  

    exec("svn update /home/homeuser/path/to/working/dir", $info); //svn update with full path

    print_r($info);
```

how to get around ?

Answer (score 2):

First, it seems like a bad idea to have a PHP script do this. But anyway, if you must - you could try creating a shell script to do the svn update and then use the PHP [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function to execute that script.

Comment: You'll still have the same permission issue.  Your custom script will execute as apache so any commands it executes will also be as apache.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you'll be able to do with PHP to fix this - it's all in the *nix permissions.

The "apache" user will need to be given permission to execute `svn update`.

Comment: "The "apache" user will need to be given permission to execute svn update." how to do this ??

Comment: I'd answer that but I'm not a server admin guy.  Perhaps open a new question on ServerFault or SuperUser?